# Dynamic 2d array in lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I want to have a 2D array in Lisp . But each row can have different number of elements(At max 5). So I thought of maintaining another single list to store the current sizes of each row, and update them whenever required.

So, my code goes like this :

```
(setq N (read))
(setq myMatrix (make-array (list N 5)))
(setq sizeArray (make-array N:fill-pointer N))
(dotimes (i N)
    (setf (aref sizeArray i) 0)
)
```

Now after that I am having a loop to fill elements per row like this :

```
(dotimes (i N)
  //Here I need to take input in each row until user presses -1.It is sure he can't insert more than 5 items in each row.
)
```

How this can be done ? Please help. I tried something like this :

```
(setq item (read-line))
(setf (aref myMatrix i (nthcdr i sizeArray)) item)
```

But it did not worked.

Comment: In which way did it not work?  Anyway, instead of using 2D arrays and keeping track of the number of elements in each row, I think it would be easier to either fill the unused positions with some dummy value (_e.g._ `-1` or `nil`), or to use a vector of vectors.

Comment: `Nthcdr` works on lists, not on arrays.  I think you want `(aref size-array i)` there.

Comment: `N:fill-pointer` is the symbol `fill-pointer` in the package `n`.  I think that you are missing a space there.

Comment: Note that the default readtable upcases everything it reads, so camel case does not make any sense.

Comment: Also, `//` does not introduce a comment.  Line comments start with one or more `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in Common Lisp can have fill pointers, which provides a way to treat an array as something which can grow and extend its length.  Your 2-D array could be realized as an array of arrays with fill pointers.  E.g.:

```
(defun make-row-resizeable-array (rows max-columns)
  "Returns an array of length ROWS containing arrays
of length MAX-COLUMNS, but with a fill pointer initially
set to 0."
  (make-array rows
              :initial-contents (loop for i from 0 below rows
                                   collect (make-array max-columns
                                                       :fill-pointer 0))))
```

This would let you do:

```
CL-USER> (let ((array (make-row-resizeable-array 6 5)))
           (vector-push 'x (aref array 2))
           (vector-push 'y (aref array 2))
           (vector-push 'z (aref array 2))
           (vector-push 'a (aref array 3))
           (vector-push 'b (aref array 3))
           array)
;=> #(#() #() #(X Y Z) #(A B) #() #())
```

you can get the lengths easily too:

```
CL-USER> (map 'list 'length *)
;=> (0 0 3 2 0 0)
```

You can get individual elements from the array with a nested **aref** call:

```
(let ((array (make-row-resizeable-array 6 5)))
  (vector-push 'x (aref array 2))
  (vector-push 'y (aref array 2))
  (vector-push 'z (aref array 2))
  (vector-push 'a (aref array 3))
  (vector-push 'b (aref array 3))
  (let ((row 3)
        (col 1))
    (aref (aref array row) col)))
;=> B
```

Comment: And how to get ith row jth column value say I want 3rd row first column value like : X

Comment: Main problem was not to fill the array but to access elements

Comment: It's just like accesing an array of arrays, you just say `(aref (aref ...) ...)`.  I just made an update.

Comment: "Main problem was not to fill the array but to access elements" While I see that you were asking about that in the very last sentence of your question, the title and first sentence "Dynamic 2d array in lisp; I want to have a 2D array in Lisp" sounded like you wanted a way to have a 2d array with dynamically sized rows. As for setting them, I illustrated that with the **vector-push**.  Note that if you do `(dotime (i rows) (loop-for-user-input (vector-push (user-input) (aref array i)))`, you build the structure that you want.

Comment: And what about accessing length of only ith row ? and not whole matrix

Comment: @python_slayer What do you mean?  I showed that in the answer with `(map 'list 'length *) ;=> (0 0 3 2 0 0)`.  The length of row n is just `(length (aref array n))`.